# does not have field named

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a mistake I cannot understand when initializing member data in an inherited class with two different methods I thought they should be theoretically identical.

```
class gSolObject
    {
    public:
        gSolObject();
        virtual ~gSolObject(){}
        bool   isCollisionObject;
    };

class gPlanetObject : public gSolObject
    {
    public:
        gPlanetObject();
       ~gPlanetObject(){};
    };

gSolObject::gSolObject():isCollisionObject(1)
            {
            }

gPlanetObject::gPlanetObject():gSolObject(),isCollisionObject(0)
            {
            }
```

I get an error class **'*gPlanetObject' does not have any field named 'isCollisionObject***'.

However when I put the initialization right into the constructor's brackts {..} instead:

```
gPlanetObject::gPlanetObject():gSolObject()
            {
            isCollisionObject=0;
            }
```

It compiles fine. Why would that be?

EDIT: This also does not work

```
gPlanetObject::gPlanetObject():gSolObject(),gSolObject::isCollisionObject(0)
```

It writes **'expected class-name before '(' token'**

Comment: I don't think a duplicate? My class constructor is explicit?

Comment: `class gPlanetObject : public gSolObject`, `gPlanetObject::gPlanetObject():gSolObject(),isCollisionObject(0)`. You're trying to initialize 'isCollisionObject' which is a member of the parent class.

Comment: You're trying to initialize `gSolObject::isCollisionObject` in the constructor for a derived class `gPlanetObject`. Read the linked answer.

Comment: ohh ok. I don't like that base class constructor.. it seems awkward.. in the other post reassignment is mentioned as problematic. Why is that?

Comment: That's the solution you showed above as "compiles fine" (`isCollisionObject = 0;`)

Comment: I know, but it is not good to do so? I have already used the code and going back would imply changing a lot of code if I want to implement a new baseconstructor..

Comment: @user2856452 as said in my edited answer, if the value is always the same, use default value instead of this

Comment: If it were always the same I would not have posted this question.. I need for each derived class a different variable to be inititalized, e.g. isCollisionObject, isFlyingObject etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't initialize member variables declared in base classes, because **the base class constructor has already initialized them.**  All base constructors execute before member constructors.

You can reassign it.  Or you can call a base class constructor that takes an argument and initializes its members with that value.

Comment: I read in the above duplicate post that reassignment is not good practice.. why is that?

Comment: OK I decided to reassign, since nobody knows why this is bad practice... I am happy with it. thaks

Comment: @user2856452: There are reasons to prefer the ctor-initializer list.  Mostly for `const` objects, which can't be assigned, and expense of default-constructing some types, which doesn't apply to `bool`.

Comment: Good to know.. I have a lot of derived classes and they take different bool initializations than the base class. It would be hell to reassign. Also I find it difficult to read the ctor initializer list, I would get lost with several initializations in my derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

Edited : You can't call a method of a uninitialized object (here `gSolObject`) and that's why it works when you execute `isCollisionObject(0)` in the constructor. Furthermore, if you always set it to 0, then you should use default value in the gSolObject constructor.

Comment: Still not working. Now it writes expected class-name before '(' token|

Comment: There's no method here and it would not work to write `isCollisionObject(0)` in the constructor body.